# Append column names as a row value

Tags: r, dataframe, append

suppose I have the following data frame. The idea is to be able to extract the names of the columns that contain a "1" as a value, and append them in a new data frame with the same "id".

```
db<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1=c(0,0,0,1,0,1),col2=c(0,0,1,1,0,0),col3=c(0,0,0,0,0,1),col4=c(1,0,0,0,0,0))

  id col1 col2 col3 col4
1  1    0    0    0    1
2  2    0    0    0    0
3  3    0    1    0    0
4  4    1    1    0    0
5  5    0    0    0    0
6  6    1    0    1    0

db2<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),cols=c("col4","-","col2","col1,col2","-","col1,col4"))

  id      cols
1  1      col4
2  2         -
3  3      col2
4  4 col1,col2
5  5         -
6  6 col1,col3
```

Comment: the last row should be `col1,col3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the rows with `apply`, subset the `names` where the column values are 1, `paste` it together to create the 'cols' column in the new `data.frame` 'db2'.  If needed, change the blanks (`""`) to `-`

```
db2 <- data.frame(db[1], cols = apply(db[-1], 1, function(x)
       paste(names(x)[x==1], collapse=",")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
db2$cols[db2$cols== ""] <- "-"
db2
#  id      cols
#1  1      col4
#2  2         -
#3  3      col2
#4  4 col1,col2
#5  5         -
#6  6 col1,col3
```

---

Or we can vectorize it in `base R`

```
m1 <- (NA^!db[-1]) * col(db[-1])
m1[] <- colnames(m1)[m1]
v1 <- do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(m1), sep=","))
db2 <- data.frame(db[1], cols =  gsub(",?NA,?", "", v1))
```

Comment: Excellent! so, final code would be. db<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1=c(0,0,0,1,0,1),col2=c(0,0,1,1,0,0),col3=c(0,0,0,0,0,1),col4=c(1,0,0,0,0,0))
db2 <- cbind(db[1], cols = apply(db[-1], 1, function(x) paste(names(x)[x==1], collapse=",")))
db2$cols<-as.character(db2$cols)
db2$cols[db2$cols=='']<-"-"

Answer (score 1):

Another option using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(db)

db[, .(.(names(row <- unlist(.SD))[row == 1])), by = id]

#    id        V1
# 1:  1      col4
# 2:  2          
# 3:  3      col2
# 4:  4 col1,col2
# 5:  5          
# 6:  6 col1,col3
```

Or if you want to add it as a new column

```
db[, cols := .(.(names(row <- unlist(.SD))[row == 1])), by = id]


#    id col1 col2 col3 col4      cols
# 1:  1    0    0    0    1      col4
# 2:  2    0    0    0    0          
# 3:  3    0    1    0    0      col2
# 4:  4    1    1    0    0 col1,col2
# 5:  5    0    0    0    0          
# 6:  6    1    0    1    0 col1,col3
```

note the code above creates a column of lists, not a character-vector column as in akrun's answer. If you want a character vector column, replace

`.(.(names(row <- unlist(.SD))[row == 1]))`

with

`paste(names(row <- unlist(.SD))[row == 1], collapse = ',')`

Comment: very impressive. Thanks